# Search Replace in MySQL: remove directory structure but keep filename

Tags: mysql

I am changing directory structures in a Drupal installation and need to remove all path data except the file name itself.

So the basic structure is:

```
+-------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| entity_type | bundle       | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | language | delta | field_filename_value                                                             | field_filename_format |
+-------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

The filename is stored in `field_filename_value`. Here's a sample record:

```
+-------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| entity_type | bundle       | deleted | entity_id | revision_id | language | delta | field_filename_value                                                             | field_filename_format |
+-------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| node        | presentation |       0 |        11 |          11 | und      |     0 | /really long path name/with lots of words/167 Clarence Ashley - Coo Coo Bird.mp3 | NULL                  |
+-------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

That ridiculous filename value needs to be changed from:

```
 /really long path name/with lots of words/167 Clarence Ashley - Coo Coo Bird.mp3
```

To this:

```
167 Clarence Ashley - Coo Coo Bird.mp3
```

Setting aside the bad practice of using spaces in file/directory names, how would you correct this? Is it possible using MySQL features alone?

As an added challenge, some files may be more than 2 directories deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use substring_index

select substring_index('http://www.example.com/dev/archive/examples/test.htm','/',-1)

(both above are fully from

[MySQL String Last Index Of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796340/mysql-string-last-index-of)

How you would use it is easy, but just to explain, you select the last index of the / and then do another substring function to cut off anything to the left of it