# MySql Trimming characters till a space

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I Trim (remove) all characters from the Right of a string upto the first space?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
set @s:='May the Gods watch over your battles, my friend!';

select if(length(@s) < 10,@s,left(@s,10)) a;

#output from above: 'May the Go'

#desired output: 'May the'
```

To avoid such odd outputs like `May the Go` I'm trying to trim all characters from the right, upto the first space, so the output is `May the`.

How can this be done in the sql statement itself. I could not find a built in function that'll do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in Microsoft SQL, it  should work if you replace CHARINDEX with INSTR

```
select substring(@s,1,charindex(' ',reverse(@s)))
```

Added a my SQL fiddle version below, works a bit different than in Microsoft SQL

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/44718

```
select @s,left(@s,10-locate(' ',reverse(@s)));
```

Example within the database

```
select theFld, 
CASE    
     WHEN  length(theFld) <= 20 THEN theFld  
     ELSE
        left(theFld,20-locate(' ',reverse(left(theFld,20))))   
     END  as Abbr 
FROM example;
```

See this SQL fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/beac7/6

Comment: Nothing. Just returns a blank.

Comment: Ah! Locate is MySql's equivalent of charindex (or at least is what works here)

Comment: Your solution uses 'reverse', but still outputs data in the right direction. How does it do that?

Comment: So, I did it like this (using the table I'll be using): `select if(length(string) > 20,concat(left(string,20-locate(' ',reverse(string))),'>>>'),string) a from string;` Hope I'm not doing anything incorrectly. Thanks

Comment: Guess I spoke too soon. Added it to the main app, and discovered it wont work. How do I build the sql using my actual table and it's columns?

Comment: See revised answer and new fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way :

```
.....
.....
--define max length for the extracted text
set @length:=10;
set @result = 
          --check if either the last extracted character or... 
          --the character next to the last is a space (or both are spaces)  
          if(substring(@s, @length, 2) LIKE '% %',  
          --if true, extract using simple left()'
            left(@s,@length),
          --else, use the same simple left() operation then remove all characters.. 
          --starting from the right-most until the first space found
            replace(left(@s,@length), substring_index(left(@s, @length), ' ', -1), '')
          );
```

**[[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/44702)]**

For reference : [MySQL String Last Index Of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796340/mysql-string-last-index-of)

Comment: Works well, but is a overkill :-)

Comment: which part do you think is overkill? I agree that you may be able to use `substring()` with `locate()` instead of `replace()`, but the `if()` check is still necessary as far as I can see. For instance in a case when `@length:=7`

Comment: I don't think it is overkill, he added a lot comments to show what is going on in the code.  My SQL-Server example in my answer is shorter, but has no comments.